# Client-Server architecture: 100% Android (Android as a server) or Java EE+Android?

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, architecture, client-server, distributed-computing

## Context

I am considering going into a client-server architecture with Java. The idea is that several Android tablets (let's say around 15) need to display a content from a server. Content can vary times to times (e.g. day display v/s night display). Furthermore, tablets will also display a **<kbd>`Yes`</kbd>** / **<kbd>`No`</kbd>** ( or a Green / Red ) button plus a **`free-text`** comment field.

Comments are gathered and sent daily as a reporting via email.

So there is a double-way communication:

- **Server** send to **client**s content to display, content may be updated
- **Client**s send feedback to **server** ( <kbd>`Yes`</kbd> / <kbd>`No`</kbd> + a free text )

I tried to look for best practices but I couldn't get accurate answer as it's pretty assumed that a server/client architecture leads to a J2EE-Android Java programming.

## Here is my questions: [*Which*] *of the following solutions is the best practice?*

- **Solution 1**: 100% Android. Another tablet is acting like a server, 
   centralizing content to display and gathering feedback.
  This tablet identifies the day comments and send by mail.
  Server only costs an extra tablet. No real server coding.
- **Solution 2**: Classic Java EE/Android Architecture. It requires an extra server unit ( rent a virtual one or buy a physical one ) and extra programming, but can provide JSP pages so a Web-App to display comments. 
  A dedicated server seems to be more powerful. However, there are more and more powerful
  tablets now.
- **Solution 3**: non-Java EE(e.g. **`C#`**, **`PHP`**) + Android Architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** Which of the following solutions [ 1) 2) 3) ] is the best practice?

**A:** price-wise / time-wise / performance-wise the 1) but scaleability-wise may get into issues once moving from 1:15 answers summary per day to some 1:1.000.000 or 1:10.000.000 range.

**`ZeroMQ`** would be my option of a first choice. It has all the strongest parts on your side { price-wise / time-wise / performance-wise } and also the scaleability & performance & rapid-prototyping-wise.

With this said, you will not spend a single man*day-efforts on building anythibng but the functionality you need for the task to be done. ZeroMQ does the rest on the smart message-passing side. It creates ( well, it has already created ) a **framework** ( rather than a set of low-level elements ).

Building atop of this framework allows you to focus on your primary goal - the service ( not on the low-level details of the supporting elements ).

Thus you may abstract from performance-scaling ( ZeroMQ allow you to re-use the knowledge of the designers, who have bought in all necessary, including a support for **failure-resilient**, **self-healing** & **perfomance-scaleable** scenarios, whithout a need to re-design your top-level services.

That is worth literally millions-of-man*days of top-class experts' efforts you would hardly ever have both a budget & time to (re)-spend to get any close of what you have in ZeroMQ framework ready for your high-level tasks in your Project already available.

In case your **economy-of-scale** works feasible for 15 tablets (users) with Android UI ( meaning you have to master the Android side anyway ), go get familiar with ZeroMQ as re-use it's bindings for this to match and go ( many bindings available and stable already for many years for many (if not all) other production-grade languages ( Ada, C, C#, C++, Erlang, F#, FORTRAN, Go, java, LISP, Node.js, pascal, perl, PHP, Python, Objective-C, Scala, Smalltalk ... to name just a few ) thus your intellectual efforts invested in this area **will get re-paid** back on further Projects  rather than to get a naked exposure without any ROI spent on that ).

### What is the next best step?

My recommendation would be to spend time with Pieter HINTJENS' book "Code Connected, Volume 1". Pieter, a co-father of ZeroMQ framework, has shared a lot of insights about how to survive in an environment of distributed, failure-prone process-to-process messaging. Indeed worth time spent on his great insights.

---

**Nota Bene**

**Q:** Have you defined what is your *best-practice*'s **metrics**?

**A:** No. This may ( *and will* ) deform answers you may expect to receive.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not see any 'Android'-specific thing here. You should not tie yourself to it, I suppose.

I think your first solution (to use tablet as a server) is NOT suitable for the task. It is not extendable, it is not even stable enough. Tablet is not a real server. You will loose the possibility of using all the tools invented for server availability, performance monitoring etc.

So, certainly, you should have a separate server there. But it doesn't necessarily to be J2EE. It can be simple Netty server for a while. Or ZeroMQ one.

You should not tie yourself to 'android' in any case. All exchange with the server should be done using common and simple format. Take JSON for example. So, if the format you use, has boolean type support, whatever your clien understands, do not send boolean fields as 'Y'/'N' values. Use boolean type for that.

Comment: **First computer:** ZX Spectrum  got me, indeed, Vladislav. Enjoy the Saturday, my man!  :o)

Comment: @user3666197 ;) I think nowadays every human being older than 5 should be presented with old speccy instead of those dull iphones ;)